# VB.NET - Rename all the folders (And sub folders) in a selected folder

Tags: vb.net, directory, rename

I tried to practise, search and i didn't find a solution to how to rename all the folders and sub-folders in a desired folder. For example i want to loop trough all the folders and add **"_test"** to the end, i searched, practiced and i didn't find any great solution so i'm asking to you if you have any snippet of code, or just and idea. I started with creating an array of all the folders within a folder by doing that:

```
Dim folderArray() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(TextBoxPath.Text, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each folder In folderArray
    Dim infoParent As New IO.DirectoryInfo(folder)
    Dim folderParent = infoParent.Parent.FullName
    Dim folderName = folder.Split(IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last()
    FileSystem.Rename(folder, folderParent & "\" & folderName & "_Test")
Next
```

But that's not working, because i rename the directories, so the array is not valid **(folderArray)** because it has the old directory path.

If you have a way to do it, i'm opened to suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try do it recursively to make sure it's done at the bottom-most level first.  (might not be 100% correct code, but just to give the general idea)

```
Sub RenameFolderRecursive(path As String)
    For Each f As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        RenameFolderRecursive(f)
    Next

    IO.Directory.Move(path, path & "_test")
End Sub
```

See if that works.

Comment: Hey, thare's a stack overflow exception, like an infinite loop, anyway i've found the solution, thaks, it's very appreciated :)

Comment: Oh duh it should've been RenameFolderRecursive(f) instead of RenameFolderRecursive(path)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for recursion.  Since you don't know how many folders any given folder will contain, or how many levels deep a folder structure can be, you can't just loop through it.  Instead, write a function which solves a discrete piece of the overall problem and recurse that function.  My VB is *very* rusty so this might not be 100% valid (you'll definitely want to debug it a bit), but the idea is something like this:

```
Function RenameFolderAndSubFolders(ByVal folder as String)
    ' Get the sub-folders of the current folder
    Dim subFolders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    If subFolders.Length < 1 Then
        'This is a leaf node, rename it and return
        FileSystem.Rename(folder, folder & "_Test")
        Return
    End If

    ' Recurse on all the sub-folders
    For Each subFolder in subFolders
        RenameFolderAndSubFolders(subFolder)

        ' Rename the current folder once the recursion is done
        FileSystem.Rename(subFolder, subFolder & "_Test")
    Next
End Function
```

The idea here is simple.  Given a folder name, get all of the child folders.  If there aren't any, rename that folder.  If there are, recurse the same function on them.  This should find all of the folders and rename them accordingly.  To kick off the process, just call the function on the root folder of the directory tree you want renamed.

Comment: You and I had the same idea, but the problem is that your code would only rename the bottom-most node and do nothing otherwise, I believe.

Comment: @j.i.h.: Ah, you're right.  I need to tweak it a little for the mid-level folders...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation, very informative i'be found the solution so thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RenameAll(ByVal sDir As String)
    Try
        For Each d As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            IO.Directory.Move(d, d & "_test")
            RenameAll(d & "_test")
        Next
    Catch x As System.Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is recursive function that might do the job you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub RenameAllFolds(d As String)
    Dim subfolds() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(d)
    If subfolds.Count = 0 Then
        IO.Directory.Move(d, d & "_Test")
    Else
        For Each dir As String In subfolds
            RenameAllFolds(dir)
        Next
        IO.Directory.Move(d, d & "_Test")
    End If
End Sub
Sub Main()
    Dim inf As String = "C:\renametest"
    Dim folds() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(inf)
    For Each f As String In folds
        RenameAllFolds(f)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```